# Подсчет несобственного интеграла с помощью SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

Нашла вычисление несобственного интеграла (в моем случае от числа до бесконечности).
Проверяю кусок кода:

```
import sympy
alfaend = 34
const_f = 1/ math.exp(math.pi*math.pi*alfaend*0.006)
x = sympy.symbols('x')
f = const_f ** ( x * x)
i = sympy.integrate(f, (x, 1, oo))
print(i)
```

Выдает ошибку о том, что "`oo`" не определен, хотя в хелпе к библиотеке абсолютно так же задана бесконечность.

Если заменить на число (например, на 100000), печатает символьную строку вместо результата:

```
 Integral(0.133533980517061**(x**2), (x, 1, 100000))
```

В чем может быть проблема?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте `sympy.oo` вместо `oo`.

Comment: Попробовала. Выводит следующее:

Integral(0.133533980517061**(x**2), (x, 1, oo))

Comment: А что вы ожидаете увидеть? Число?
Укажите ссылку на Хелп.
Может, вам поможет `i.evalf()`, но нужно в хелпе уточнить!

Comment: о! нашла! если взять i = float(интеграл), то всю считается =)

Comment: >>> i.evalf()
0.0279699483698151
>>> float(i)
0.027969948369815076
Рекомендую Вам все таки хорошенько доку почитать